# CMAKE on (tortoisesvn) SVN project :: Error in configuring process, project files may be invalid

Tags: c++, svn, visual-c++, tortoisesvn, cmake

I have checked out a version of project from SVN.  Below are the different kinds of errors I got while trying to CMAKE a project from SVN. Could it be that some of the files are not **checked out**? Please, go through the three kinds of errors and help me out with it.

==================Type 1==================================
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:184 (add_subdirectory):
  add_subdirectory given source "google/gmock" which is not an existing
  directory.

==================Type 2==================================

Subversion executable was not found.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (UpLinqSVN_WC_INFO):
  Unknown CMake command "UpLinqSVN_WC_INFO".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:207 (CreateVersionInfo)

========================TYPE 3==========================================

CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
FFMPEG_AVCODEC_LIB
    linked by target "UpLinq" in directory C:/Users/Krishna/Desktop/2.5/GUI
FFMPEG_AVCORE_LIB
    linked by target "UpLinq" in directory C:/Users/Krishna/Desktop/2.5/GUI
FFMPEG_AVDEVICE_LIB
    linked by target "UpLinq" in directory C:/Users/Krishna/Desktop/2.5/GUI

Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Answer (score 0):

Error 1 indeed indicates that the CMakeLists.txt expected there to be a directory called google/gmock (relative to the CMakeLists.txt which is calling `add_subdirectory` at line 184).

Without more info, there's no way to tell if this is an error in the CMakeLists file or in the repository.

The first part of error 2 (can't find Subversion exe) looks like a custom error message.  It may be looking for a ".svn" folder in the project root, and assuming that Subversion is available.  Presumably it then looks for the Subversion exe and fails to find it (not in path maybe?)

The second part of error2 (unknown CMake command) is saying that at line 14 of CMakeLists.txt, there's a command called `UpLinqSVN_WC_INFO` being invoked.  It doesn't recognise this as a valid command, which probably means that it's defined as a [`function`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3afunction) or [`macro`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3amacro) in another CMake file somewhere.  It would need to be defined *before* it's invoked at line 14.  It could be that the CMakeLists.txt you're executing is expected to be run as part of a larger build, which would define this function before starting on your CMakeLists.txt.

Error 3 is saying that there's a CMake target called "UpLinq" (an exe or lib) which has a dependency on `${FFMPEG_AVCODEC_LIB}`.  At some point, there's probably been a [`find_library`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3afind_library) call looking for the avcodec library which has also failed.  The result of the search is held in the variable `FFMPEG_AVCODEC`, and it shows that `${FFMPEG_AVCODEC}` has a value of `FFMPEG_AVCODEC-NOTFOUND`.

If you need more help than this, you'll need to put up a copy of the relevant parts of the CMakeLists files involved, and a bit more info about your environment / directory structures.

Comment: Thank you mate, for an elaborate and complete answer. Definitely, some of the folder/files are missing while SVN download. Do you think I should be searching the repository and might be able to get those as externals or elsewhere outside the directory in some branch like folders?

Comment: It's hard to know; probably best to ask the project owners.  In the meantime, there's no harm in searching for the missing parts I suppose.